# CakePHP: Disable Security Component site wide

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have lot of AJAX functionality in my site and a component we freelanced was using CakePHP Security Component very tightly with the forms and this is lot of trouble.

How to disable Security Component site-wide in CakePHP? Just disabling it the app_controller.php is not helping because it is tightly coupled with some validation and black-hole stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you disable it in your app_controller your individual controller may have that security enabled.As my wild guess says this is what you want to do.If not let me know more about it.

```
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() && $this->action = 'add'){

        $this->Security->enabled = false;

    }

}
```

you can read more about this [here](http://life.mysiteonline.org/archives/175-Disable-the-Security-Component-in-CakePHP-only-for-Certain-Actions.html) .Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Yea, I already found this one! Was looking more like a flag that can disable the complete functionality! But I understand it might be tough to have depending on how each controller is using it!